# Visual Studio Code can't find reference to function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, ide, header-files

I'm trying to use Visual Studio for a specific project but I can't get files to link properly.
When including a header file with a defined function in another cpp file im getting an error `undefined reference to testFunc() collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Thing is, this exact same code works perfectly in Eclipse. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Test.cpp

```
#include "Other.h"

int main(){
   
    testFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

Other.h

```
#pragma once

void testFunc();
```

Other.cpp

```
#include "Other.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void testFunc(){
    cout << "HelloWorld";
}
```

When Buildung, this occours:

```
Starting build...
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\johan\cu-workspace\TEst\Test.cpp -o C:\Users\johan\cu-workspace\TEst\Test.exe
C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Temp\cck3aAZo.o: In function `main':
C:/Users/johan/cu-workspace/TEst/Test.cpp:5: undefined reference to `testFunc()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).
```

Comment: Have you added `other.cpp` to the project? Please show the build commands and its output.

Comment: Im Sorry I was talking about Visual Studio Cude. All My files are in the same folder and the launch.json references to this folder "cwd": "c:/Users/johan/cu-workspace/TEst"

Comment: Well, the build log clearly show you are not building `other.cpp`, so add it to that command.

Comment: if you use more than 1 cpp file you have to use a build tool like Makefile or CMake, soon you will have way more than 5 cpp files and then the build phase will take too long and you will complain about that, also maintain the build in launch.json is a nightmare for big CPP projects

Answer (score 0):

If you build `Other.h` and `Other.cpp` as a project, then you need to configure the linker to add Other.lib into test project.
For a simple scenario, you can have all 3 files in one project and they should build just fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to your build info:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\johan\cu-workspace\TEst\Test.cpp -o C:\Users\johan\cu-workspace\TEst\Test.exe
```

You can see that `Other.cpp` is not in your project, so you might need to add it into your project.

Since you are using VS code, you can write a simple command in terminal to build your code:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -g C:\Users\johan\cu-workspace\TEst\Test.cpp C:\Users\johan\cu-workspace\TEst\Other.cpp -o C:\Users\johan\cu-workspace\TEst\Test.exe
```

Comment: Using that seems to work, yet only for building. When I want to run the code inside of VSCode to use the terminal I'm still running into the same problem. 
I also got to work by making a few changes in the task.json, but also just for building.
Is there a way so tell VSCode to run the code via your command or including the task.json?

Comment: @JohannesK. Could you explain more about *I want to run the code inside of VSCode to use the terminal*? I didn't get the point. Since the code you provided is not very complicated, I suggest you can run the executable file in terminal with command `./Test.exe` after you build your code successfully. By the way, if you just start learning coding, I suggest to use Visual Studio for it can reduce the hassle of configuring your environment. You should spend your energy on the code itself, not on the environment configuration.